# WPML is not detecting Wordpress custom post types

Tags: wordpress

I learned how to make custom post types with the following tutorial:

http://sixrevisions.com/wordpress/wordpress-custom-post-types-guide/

It basically consist in adding this code to **function.php**:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_events' );
function create_events() {
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Events', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Event', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Event'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Event'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Event'),
    'new_item' => __('New Event'),
    'view_item' => __('View Event'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Events'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No Events found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Events found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
  );

  $supports = array('title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'revisions', 'excerpt');

  register_post_type( 'event',
    array(
      'labels' => $labels,
      'public' => true,
      'supports' => $supports
    )
  );
}
```

The [WPML](http://wpml.org/) plugin help you to translate posts to different langauges. But this option doesn't appear in the custom post types.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Click on WPML->Multilingual content setup and choose to have those custom types translatable.

There's also a notice in your Admin Dashboard saying that you didn't choose if you want that custom type translated or not.